# lost all files by using sudo mount, need help

Tags: mount

I have a urgent question which almost make me crazy now.

I used the following command for MATLAB installation:

```
sudo mount -o loop /home/study/MATLAB/R2017b/iso/iso2.iso /home/caihongzhu
```

Under `/home/study` directory, I have all my useful files. After using this command, I lost all files under the `/home/study` directory (for user caihongzhu).

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: This is the dreaded (but easily fixable) "shadow mount": https://superuser.com/questions/389255/is-it-possible-to-access-files-shadowed-by-a-mount

Comment: just a comment that I find everything under the home directory is gone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of your data is lost, it is only hidden because you mounted the Matlab iso onto your home directory. Simply unmount it again, and the original content of the directory will be visible again:

```
sudo umount /home/caihongzhu
```

Next time, do not mount anything over your existing user directories, but create a new empty directory as mount target, use `/mnt` or mount stuff using your Files manager, which automatically creates temporary mount points inside `/media/USERNAME`.

Answer (score 2):

The files aren't lost but just not visible as long as the ISO image is mounted on `/home/caihongzhu`. Just umount it to get them back:

```
umount /home/caihongzhu
```

Next time you should better use another mount point for the ISO image, for example `/mnt/`:

```
sudo mount -o loop /home/study/MATLAB/R2017b/iso/iso2.iso /mnt/
```

Then you can access the files at `/mnt/` and your files in `/home/caihongzhu/` are still visible.